# 2015/05/15 07:30:34 exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker

I am facing below issue tell me how to fix this!
command used:

```
$ sudo docker run --rm -P -p 9090:9090 --name trial godock &
$ docker run --rm -P -p 9090:9090 --name trial godock2015/05/18
03:35:25 exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH
# go version
go version go1.2.1 linux/amd64
```

**Docker file**:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get -y update
ADD server.go /src/server.go
ADD . /src
EXPOSE 9090
CMD ["go","run","/src/server.go"]
```

**server.go**:

```go
package main
import(
  "io"
  "net/http"
  "log"
  "fmt"
)
func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, req * http.Request) {
  io.WriteString(w, "hello, world!\n")
}
func main() {
  fmt.Println("Starting server")
  http.HandleFunc("/hello", HelloServer)
  err: = http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
  }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue..

Comment: small recommendation: It would be a lot nicer and friendlier for future readers if you used a text output rather a screenshot.

Comment: side note: don't use `&` but the [`-d` option](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#detached-d) of the `docker run` command

Comment: You're starting from `ubuntu`? If that's the stock upstream image... err, why would it have Go installed at all? You should at least run `apt-get -y install golang`.

Comment: (...and if that's an `ubuntu` other than the upstream public-repo one, then there isn't enough information provided in the question to reproduce the problem).

Comment: StackOverflow "Snippet" support is for JavaScript only, and should not be used for any other language.

Comment: What does `docker run --rm ubuntu go version` return?

Answer (score 0):

### Install Go In Your Container

You mention your file is similar to this:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get -y update
ADD server.go /src/server.go
ADD . /src
EXPOSE 9090
CMD ["go","run","/src/server.go"]
```

Amend the `RUN` command to read something like the following to install the go tools:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y golang
```

### Invoke Go Explicitly

You should reference the `go` command explictly with a full path in the `CMD` instruction at the end of your Docker file (see the [CMD reference](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd)).

Amend the `CMD` of your sample Dockerfile with:

CMD ["/usr/bin/go","run","/src/server.go"]

Comment: Not a safe assumption, if is the upstream `ubuntu` Dockerfile base.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: oh I wasn't at all implying it would already be in the image, just that I'd hope OP would have thought of installing the go tools if he's using go (which apparently he did).

Comment: I'm... not convinced that the information given demonstrates that conclusively. The writing in the question, even as amended, is a bit fuzzy in terms of how it presents details -- we don't know that the `godock` used in the demonstration is the same Dockerfile for which source is given. `FROM ubuntu` is pretty clear; if we had something that started `FROM godock`, I'd have fewer questions.

Comment: In short -- sure, the OP may understand that they need to install Go, but may be unclear on the steps needed to do that correctly, in the right container's dependency chain. We wouldn't have someone here if they were doing everything right, after all.